# Efficient way to check if unicode string is NFC in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, normalization, python-unicode, unicode-normalization

I want to check if a string is already in NFC form. Currently I do:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s) == s
```

I am doing this for a large number of strings, so I would like to be efficient. The above method seems wasteful. It converts to NFC, and then does a string comparison.

Is there a more efficient way to do it? I have considered:

```
len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s)) == len(s)
```

This avoids the string comparison. But I am not sure this is always correct. This works if NFC normalization always changes the length of a non NFC string. Is that a valid assumption?

Any other ideas?

Comment: I would venture that the conversion itself is much slower than the string comparison, there's not much to be gained by switching to `len`. It's worth trying a quick timing test just to see.

Comment: Probably. Ideally I would like to avoid the conversion entirely. I really have no need for the NFC value.

Comment: (1) don't use `str` name. It is builtin. (2) use `s = nfc(s)` instead of `nfc(s) == s`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian (1) thanks, yeah that was a bad choice. i've updated. (2) i don't understand. one is assignment, the other is equality, how can i replace one with the other?

Comment: @user2771609: don't check whether it is in NFC form, make it NFC.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian but i need a validator, not a converter. you are asking me to solve a problem i don't have, and to ignoring the problem i actually have....

Comment: @user2771609: you might have noticed that I've posted it as a *comment*, not an answer. In many cases, using `s = nfc(s)` simplifies code compared to `if nfc(s) == s: this else: that` alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalising doesn't necessarily change the length of a string. For example, `'Ω'` (U+2126) becomes `'Ω'` (U+03A9) after NFC.

There is a normalisation ["quick check" property](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#NFC_QC_Optimization) in the Unicode database to test whether a character is already normalised, but unfortunately Python's `unicodedata` module doesn't expose it. However, `unicodedata.normalize()` does use this property to avoid doing any extra work if the string is already normalised—it simply returns the input string.

To access this property, you will either need to compile a table yourself from the Unicode Character Database, or use a broader Unicode library with Python bindings (like [PyICU](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/)).

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, `normalize()` always returns a new string instance (understandably, in retrospect) so you can't use `is` to avoid a string comparison.

Comment: @tripleee `normalize('NFC', a) is a` is `True` for me on both 2.7.8 and 3.4.0. The [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/unicodedata.c#l817) is also pretty clear. You shouldn't need to use `is` anyway, as `==` performs the same optimisation.

Comment: My bad, I checked on a really old Python 2.5 which I happened to have open; but I get the same behavior on 2.6.6, too.  `is` should be faster when there is a mismatch; in this case, `==` will proceed to compare the strings, while `is` will already have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.8 it exposes the needed check. Quote from the Python docs:

> unicodedata.**is_normalized**(form, unistr)
>
> Return whether the Unicode string unistr is in the normal form 'form'. Valid values for form are ‘NFC’, ‘NFKC’, ‘NFD’, and ‘NFKD’.
>
> ```
> New in version 3.8.
> ```

I wanted everything to be in NFC, but checking for NFD (so i could convert only those) did not work: all NFC strings passed the NFD check! My solution was then to test if a string is **not** NFC, and if  so then do the conversion.